# trap the click event for a button that is in the resourcedictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to trap the `Click` event for a button that is in a `ResourceDictionary` but I'm getting an error:

```
'WpfApplication1.MyResourceDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'GetTemplateChild' and no extension method 'GetTemplateChild' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfApplication1.MyResourceDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

MyResourceDictionay.xaml.cs looks like this:

```
namespace WindowsApplication1
{
  partial class MyResourceDictionary
  {
    public virtual void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
     Button myButton = this.GetTemplateChild("Crap") as Button;
    }
  }
}
```

MyResourceDictionay.xaml looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     x:Class="WindowsApplication1.MyResourceDictionary" 
     x:ClassModifier="public">

  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpandablePropertyEditorTemplate">
    <Button x:Name="Crap"  Foreground="White" Background="White">
      <Image Source="Controls\check.png"/>
    </Button>
  </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to search inside of a resource dictionary, you should be using the function FindName(string), not GetTemplateChild(string).

Even if you are searching for a child control within the template of the current control, you should use Template.FindName(string, FrameworkElement templatedParent) not GetTemplateChild(string).

If this doesn't help, please expand you description.

If you have a code behind file, usually you can add the handler right in the XAML and have it attach to the code behind (even if the control is in a dictionary you can often do this).

I hope this helps.